# Need help solving an equation that includes percentages.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three groups, Group A, Group B, Group C, of Sam's friends decided to buy a watch as a memorable gift for his birthday. They contributed 1200 AED in the ratio of 3:4:5. How much did each group contribute?

Group A : Group B: Group C ⟺3:4:5⟺3x:4x:5x.
3x+4x+5x=1200AED
Solve for x:
12x=1200⟺x=100AED
This gives us that Group A contributed 3x=3 ⋅ 100=300 AED,
Group B contributed 4x=4 ⋅ 100=400 AED,
Group C contributed 5x=5 ⋅ 100=500 AED.

a) What is the percentage is the highest contribution with respect to the total?

b) What is the percentage is the lowest contribution with respect to the total?

Answer (score 2):

(a) The highest contribution comes from Group C: $500$ AED. Of the total contribution $1200$, Group C contributed $$\dfrac {500}{1200} \times 100\% = \frac 5{12} \times 100\% = \;\;?$$

(b) Do the same for the lowest contribution, and the percentage of this contribution with respect to the total of $1200$ AED. The smallest contribution was from Group A: $300$ AED:
So calculate $$\frac{300}{1200} \times 100\% = \frac 14 \times 100\%$$ to find the percentage of the total that this contribution amounts to.